# Data send by Debugging

Tags: qt, debugging

I've got a server, which ought to send `image's` **QByteArray** `toBase64` format (attached in xml) to the client. Server itself works fine when I `Run` it, but when `started Degubbing` instead of just Running. The server doesn't send a image xml with appended QByteArray. I can not understand what is the reason for that? It shows no error while server started by Debugging, by the way. The image is on the server side and its server task to send an image. Here is how server extracts the image by method getVCardImage:

```
QByteArray &VCardExtensionPrivate::getVCardImage(const QString &imageName,
                                                 const QString& type) 
{
    if(!m_image.isNull()) m_image.clear();
    QString imagePath = QString("%1/avatars/%2").arg(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath())
                        .arg(imageName);
    QImage image;
    image.load(imagePath);
    if(!image.isNull()) {
        QBuffer buffer(&m_image);
        buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        image.save(&buffer, imageType(type.toUpper()));
    }
    return m_image;
}
```

**And I do save QByteArray into xml:**

```
QDomElement newNodeTag = doc.createElement(QString("BINVAL"));
QDomText newNodeText = doc.createTextNode(getVCardImage(m_imagePath, photoType).toBase64());
```

Sending through

```
server()->sendPacket(xml)` \\ xml is QDomElement with <BINVAL>
```

**Start Run** works fine!

```
<BINVAL>`QByteArray(toBase64) format`<\BINVAL>
```

**Start Debugging**

```
<BINVAL>`empty without any QByteArray`<\BINVAL>
```

Comment: Where does the image data come from originally? Add some of the server's code.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Rectified!